# CSS allow text selection within an element only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here I am trying to achieve where user can select text within an element only, e.g: `textfield` or `textarea` In these if we have text in textfield then its allowed only to select text within a textfield area, its wont select outer text.
How can we do this in the case of `div` tag? any help will be appreciated.

```
<div>
    <div id="one"> some content will be here... </div>
    <div id="two"> text should be select from this div only.. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will you have more divas, or just two divas (`one` and `two`)?

Comment: it can be more right now its 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the style `user-select: none` on `#one` like this:

```css
#one {
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="one"> some content will be here... </div>
    <div id="two"> text should be select from this div only.. </div>
</div>
```

---

You can also put `user-select: none` on the parent and apply it back to specific children within the parent to make them selectable.

```css
.no-user-select {
  user-select: none;
}

.has-user-select {
  user-select: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="no-user-select">
    <div id="one"> some content will be here... </div>
    <div id="two" class="has-user-select"> text should be select from this div only.. </div>
    <div id="three"> cannot select from this child either </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @pretzelhammer thanks for your time.but if we give this css to div one it wont select div one content but its allowed to select parent div content!!

Comment: how can we restrict to user to allow him to select only within an element it should not be select its parent content as well or child.

Comment: thank you so much for giving your valuable time here.

Comment: @Kanekar, I figured you need this for every div except the current div. It turned out to be as easy as shelling pears. Oh my bad english :-)

Comment: @s.kuznetsov right pretzelhammer given the same answer :-)